# Set input field of date format other than "date" type in a particular format

Tags: php

I want to create an input field for date in a particular format of d-m-Y. How to do that without using type="date" which does not work with my implementation. It shows date only upto 12

Comment: Why not using a datepicker?

Comment: cannot use it in my form. is there any other way?

Answer (score -1):

You can use a plugin likethis 
http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

Comment: Posting the links only is not proper answering.

Comment: I am new to stack, was just trying to help and point to starting point. Lesson learned, caused me 2 points for the downvote :).